# Equal of req.on('data') in Koa

Tags: node.js, koa

What is the Equal of below code in Koa.js :

```
req.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stil access the node.js request but you should not do that!

```
var req = this.request.req;
```

Using `co-body` you can parse *JSON* and *form-encoded* requests. If you want to handle another body type, you have to write your own middleware.

Here is a dummy middleware to handle XML requests:

```
var raw = require('raw-body');
var parseXML = require('xml2js').parseString;

function xml(req, opts) {
  req = req.req || req;

  // Parse Content-Type
  var type = (req.headers['content-type'] || '').split(';')[0];
  if (type === 'application/xml') {
    return function(done) {
      raw(req, opts, function(err, str){
        if (err) return done(err);
        try {
          // Parse XML request
          parseXML(str, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            done(null, result);
          });
        } catch (err) {
          err.status = 400;
          err.body = str;
          done(err);
        }
      });
    };
  } else {
    // Invalid request
    return function(done) {
      var err = new Error('Unsupported or missing content-type');
      err.status = 415;
      done(err);
    };
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var body = yield xml(this);
```